# Modern Wyeast vs Original vs XL

Tags: yeast, wyeast

Am getting back into home brewing after a decade-plus hiatus. Call me "born again," at the risk of offending some (I hope none are).

When I started in the 1990's, the cultures from Wyeast were 50ml (I believe), and a starter was recommended for a 5 US gal (19 l) batch. Chris White's alternative becomes a thing; the big advantage is the "pitchable quantity" -- no starter needed for a 5 gal batch. Wyeast first responds with a product similar to that from White Labs, though packaged differently (the "shampoo tube"), then sees the light and introduces the XL pack, putatively a pitchable quantity, with the advantage of the nutrient pack (the "little rascal") inside, just like the Wyeast Original Recipe, to wake up the wee beasties so they can hit the ground running at pitching. I don't see the XL product any longer.

My question (yes, there is one in here): Are the new homebrew smack-packs from Wyeast like the original, or do they have a cell count similar to what was in the XL pack? Yes, I can read the cell counts on the new packages, but am uncertain how they compare to what was in the original and XL formats.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed since the 90s - even in the past decade. Yeast, malts, hops, other constituents, have all become more efficient, consistent and marketed. Chris White has several Q&A sessions on yeast, fermentation and brewing in general. You may want to search up some of his stuff but maybe in particular, this podcast (https://beersmith.com/blog/2021/03/20/pitching-yeast-with-dr-chris-white-beersmith-podcast-232/) about pitching yeast. It's a couple years old but should have more updated info that when you last brewed.

Good luck, and welcome back!